# how to push button above keyboard while keeping bottom navigation view under the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

my button should be always visible above keyboard while my  bottom navigation view should disappear while soft keyboard is open. tried setting only button `fitSystemWindows = true` and navigation bar to `fitSystemWindows =false` but nothing changed:either both views are shown above keyboard with `adjustResize` or both aren't shown with  `adjustPan` . i know i can detect when keyboard is open and hide navigation view but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: you can try to put the content of the fragment in a scrollview and use adjustPan.

Comment: @sadat not working. i tried with isScrollContainer setted to false or true too.  is there a way for the button to behave like the edittext and not be overlapped by keyboard?